# oracle apex Alertify plugin generated messages with SOUND

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, alertify

Just wondering if it's possible to play any sound (like beep) when generating a success/failure message using Alertify on an oracle apex page?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I managed to do this by adding one more true action in the dynamic action which executes following javascript        var audio = new Audio('path/test.mp3');
audio.play();

Comment: I feel sorry for the people who have to work in the cubicles surrounding the people who are forced to use your application... I hope you at least make it configurable so they can turn it off :)

Comment: Hi Jeffery, actually this is a mandatory requirement, so need to make it configurable so they can turn it off. But now I am trying to combine this into the Alertify plugin can you point me to the right directory in terms of how to do it? Thanks a lot.    I asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381213/oracle-apex-alertify-plugin